Authorization header not passing from backend in node.js
i'm creating a new api called "/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcheck/:u_id" it is hitting fine but the authorization header is not passing.
response from interceptor:
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:3000/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcheck/57', ok: true, …}body: {success: true, status: 200, message: 'Previous payment Details found', data: {…}}headers: HttpHeadersheaders: Map(2) {'content-length' => Array(1), 'content-type' => Array(1)}lazyInit: nulllazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(2) {'content-length' => 'content-length', 'content-type' => 'content-type'}[[Prototype]]: Objectok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 4url: "http://localhost:3000/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcheck/57"[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase 'KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK' false

my interceptor:
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest,HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, finalize,catchError,map, throwError, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { LoaderService } from '../loader/loader.service';
import { LocalstorageService } from '../localStorage/localstorage.service';
import { request } from 'http'; 
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from "../auth/auth.service"
import {NotificationsService} from "../notifications/notifications.service";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private localStorage: LocalstorageService, 
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: AuthService,
    private notification: NotificationsService
  ) { }
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next:HttpHandler 
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>|any{
  //   if(req.headers){
     
  //     let token = req.headers.get("Authorization");
  //     console.log(req.headers, "INTERCEPTOR HEADERS NEW",token);
  //     if(token){
  //       console.log(token,"INTERCEPTOR HEADERS NEW TOKEN");
  //       // let splittoken = token.split(" ");
  //       // let newtoken = splittoken[1];
  //       // this.localStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(newtoken));
  //     }else{
  //       console.log("INTERCEPTOR HEADERS NEW TOKEN NOT FOUND");
  //     }
  //   }
    this.loaderService.open();
    if(req.url.includes('login')){
      return next.handle(req.clone({
        setHeaders:{
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
      })).pipe(
        
        finalize(()=>{
        this.loaderService.close();
      }));
    }
    const token_jwt: any = this.localStorage.getItem('token')||"";
    const token: any = token_jwt;
    const jwt = token;
    console.log(token,"<<==================INTERCEPTOR TOKEN is --------------->",('Bearer '+ jwt));
    const authReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
      }
    });
    const corsHeader: HttpRequest<any> = authReq.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
    });

    return next.handle(corsHeader)
      .pipe(
      
        map((event:HttpEvent<any>)=>{
          if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
             const headers = event.headers.keys();
            console.log(event, "KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK", headers.includes('authorization'));
            if (headers.includes('authorization')) {
              const token: any = event.headers.get('authorization');
              console.log('parsed, Token:', token.split(" "));
              // Use the token for subsequent requests or store it in local storage
             
              const split = token.split(" ");
             
              this.localStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(split[1]));
            }
          
            if(event.status==200){

              this.notification.showAlert(event?.body?.message);
            }
          }
          return event;
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.loaderService.close();
        }),
        catchError(async (err:HttpResponse<any>)=>{
          if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            if(err.status==401 ){
              console.log(err,"EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
              this.loginService.tokencheck().subscribe((data:any)=>{
                console.log(data,"INTERCEPTOR 401 STATUS RSPONSE FROM NODE IS")
              });

            }
           
          }
           return throwError(err?.body?.message);
        })
      )
      ;
  }
}

my api file:
const dbMiddleware = require('../db/dbmiddleware');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcheck/:u_id", async (req, res) => {
//   console.log(req.params.u_id,"USER ID AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    try{
        let user_id = { user_id: +req.params.u_id };
        let getdata = await dbMiddleware.getConditionalDataDesc('Account', user_id, '','created_at');
        console.log(getdata.data,"GET DATA VALUES",res);
        if (getdata.success && getdata.data.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, status: 200, message: "Previous payment Details found", data: getdata.data[0] });
        } else {
            res.status(422).json({ success: false, status: 422, message: "No payment details found currently", data: getdata.data });
        }
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, status: 500, message: "failure to fetch payment details", data: error });
    }

});

module.exports = router;

my authorizer middleware:
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'g_cred1.json');

let c_id;
readFile(filePath, 'utf-8')
  .then((data) => {
    c_id = JSON.parse(data);
 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // console.log(err, "error reading google json file");
  });

// console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
let access_token;
let refresh_token;
const dbmiddleware = require('../db/dbmiddleware');

const googlemiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const client = new OAuth2Client({
    clientId: c_id.web.client_id,
    clientSecret: c_id.web.client_secret,
    redirectUri: c_id.web.redirect_uris[0],
  });
  const headerToken = req.headers.authorization ? req.headers.authorization : req.rawHeaders[1];
  if (!headerToken) {
    res.status(401).json({ status: 401, success: false, message: "Not Authorized" });
  }
  const token = headerToken.split(' ');
  try {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token[1],
      audience: c_id.web.client_id,
    });
    console.log(req,"ORIGINAZL DATA id ",res);

    req.decodedjwt = ticket.payload;

    next();
  } catch (err) {

    if (err) {
      try {
        const emailRegex = /"email":"([^"]+)"/;
        const match = err.message.match(emailRegex);
        let email;
        if (match) {
          email = match[1];
          // // console.log('Extracted email:', email);
        } else {
          // // console.log('Email not found in the error message.');
          email = '';
        }
        // // console.log(err,'Extracted email:', email);
        const result = await dbmiddleware.getConditionalData('user', 'email', email);
        const newAccessToken = await refreshAccessToken(client, result.data[0].refresh_token);
        // console.log(newAccessToken, "newAccessToken");
        // Set the Authorization header in the response
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
          idToken: newAccessToken,
          audience: c_id.web.client_id,
        });
        req.decodedjwt = ticket.payload;
        res.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
     
         next();
      } catch (error) {
        // console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
      }
    }
  }
};

const refreshAccessToken = async (client, refreshToken) => {
  try {
    const { tokens } = await client.refreshToken(refreshToken);
    console.log(tokens, "tokens 1111111111111111111");
    return tokens.id_token;
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};


module.exports = googlemiddleware;

my server.js:
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();
//=====================start call routers over here====================
const registerlogin = require("./auth/registerlogin.js");
const userDetails = require("./db/userDetails.js");
const historydownload = require('./core/gethistorydownload.js');
const addupdateprofile = require('./core/add-update-profile.js');
const getprofile = require('./core/getprofile.js');
const stripe = require('./stripe/stripe-intent.js');
const tokencheck = require("./jsonmiddleware/tokencheck.js");
const paymentIntent = require('./stripe/payment-intents.js');
const stripeclientsecret = require('./stripe/stripeClientSecret.js');
const confirmPayment = require('./stripe/confirmpayment.js');
const gptgenerator = require('./core/gptgenerator.js');
const resumedownload = require('./core/resumedownload.js');
const getpaymentdetails = require("./core/getpayments.js");
const getstoredcarddetails = require("./stripe/storedcardpayment.js");
const makepayments4mstoredcard =require('./stripe/storedcardpaymentprocessor.js');
const storedcardresults = require('./stripe/storedcard3ds.js');
const usagedownloaddatacount = require('./core/usage-downloadcount.js');
const usagedownloadcheck = require("./core/usagecheck.js");
//----------------------- CASHFREE STARTS-------------------------------
const createOrder = require('./cashfree/createorder.js');
const getorderconfirmation = require('./cashfree/getorderconfirmation.js');
//----------------------- CASHFREE ENDS-------------------------------
//====================End calling routers after here ===================
// @ts-ignore
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
// @ts-ignore
const htmlDocx = require('html-docx-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const LRU = require('lru-cache');

const { stdout, exit } = require('process');
const app = express();
const googlemiddleware = require('./jsonmiddleware/googlemiddleware.js');
const dbmiddleware = require('./db/dbmiddleware.js');
const { create } = require("domain");


// Set up express-session
// Initialize the session middleware directly on the app object
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "blah!blah!blah!",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
// app.use(cors({
//   exposedHeaders: ['Authorization'],
// }));

const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*', // Specify your allowed origin
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'],
  credentials: true // If you need to allow cookies or other credentials
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use('/protected', googlemiddleware);
//------------------------- CASHFREE STARTS ------------------------
app.post('/protected/cashfree/createorder', createOrder);
app.post('/protected/cashfree/getorderconfirmation',getorderconfirmation)

//------------------------- CASHFREE ENDS ------------------------

app.post("/protected/resume/tokencheck", tokencheck);

app.post("/resume/authcheck", userDetails); // Mount the router under the '/authcheck' path
app.post("/registerlogin", registerlogin);
app.get('/protected/history/resume',historydownload);
app.post("/protected/history/resume/generate", gptgenerator);
app.post("/protected/history/resume/download", resumedownload);
app.post("/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcount", usagedownloaddatacount);
app.get("/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcheck/:u_id", usagedownloadcheck);
app.post('/protected/profile/addupdate',addupdateprofile);
app.get('/protected/profile/getprofile', getprofile);
app.post('protected/payment/stripe',stripe);
app.post("/protected/payments/payment-intent", paymentIntent);
app.get("/protected/payments/client-secret", stripeclientsecret);
app.post("/protected/payments/confirm-payment", confirmPayment);
app.use("/protected/payments/storedcardapi", getstoredcarddetails);
app.post("/protected/payments/storedcardpaymentsapi",makepayments4mstoredcard);
app.post("/protected/payments/storedcardsresult", storedcardresults);
app.post("/protected/details/getpayments", getpaymentdetails);//same as storedcardapi API.


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, this is the root path!');
});


const cache = new LRU({ max: 100 });
const generateHTML = require('./core/generate.js').generateHTML;



// Define an endpoint to download a resume
app.post('/protected/resume/download', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resumeData = req.body.resumeData;
    const theme = req.body.theme;

    // Generate the resume
    const resume = await generateHTML(resumeData, theme,'pdf');

    // Send the resume to the client
    // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.status(200).send(resume);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

async function convertHtmlToImage(html, theme) {
  // Create a temporary file to store the HTML
  const tempFile = fs.mkdtempSync('');
  const htmlFilePath = `${tempFile}/resume.html`;
  fs.writeFileSync(htmlFilePath, html);

  // Convert the HTML to an image using the wkhtmltopdf command-line tool
  const childProcess = spawn('wkhtmltopdf', ['--quiet', '--print-media-type', 'all', '--no-collate', '--disable-smart-shrinking', '--margin-top', '0', '--margin-bottom', '0', '--margin-left', '0', '--margin-right', '0', '--page-size', 'A4', htmlFilePath, `${tempFile}/resume.${theme}.png`]);

  // Wait for the child process to exit
  await childProcess.on('exit', () => {});

  // Read the image file
  const image = await fs.promises.readFile(`${tempFile}/resume.${theme}.png`);

  // Remove the temporary file
  fs.rmdirSync(tempFile, { recursive: true });

  // Return the image
  return image;
}


app.post('/protected/resume/render', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resumeData = req.body.resumeData;
    const theme = req.body.theme;
    const fs = require('fs').promises;
  
  const user_data = await dbmiddleware.getConditionalData('user','email',req.decodedjwt.email)  
  
    // Generate the resume
    const resume = await generateHTML(resumeData, theme,'html',user_data.data[0].u_id);
    

    const resumeresult={"resume": resume.output,"data": resume,success: true,message: "Resume generated successfully",status:200};
    console.log("RESUME  RESULT",resumeresult,"RESUME  RESULT")

    //wait for a few seconds and delete generated files after the result has been sent
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    
    await fs.unlink(resume.file); // Delete the generated resume file
    await fs.unlink(resume.json); // Delete the JSON file
    // await fs.unlink(`${resume.file}.html`);
    res.status(200).send(resumeresult);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});



const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
  
});

what is going wrong it was passing headers fine earlier now it is not what is the solution.
